# How do I prepopulate a field with calculated options, when user is editing node?

Tags: 7, entities

Say the user is creating a node. I want to display a drop down option list, with prepopulated options, based on a calculation (i.e. reference to user's groups, user's other nodes, etc...). Drupal 7.

I've had no luck with the rules, computed field, prepopulate field modules... maybe i'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter) to pre-populate your dropdown list with results returned from a custom function.

---

For example, using a form of hook_form_alter():

```
$form['field_my_field']['und']['#options'] = _my_custom_function();
```

Then make sure your function `_my_custom_function()` return's a proper array.

```
function _my_custom_function() {
    $custom_values = array();
    $custom_values['key1'] = 'value1';
    $custom_values['key2'] = 'value2';
    $custom_values['key3'] = 'value3';
    return $custom_values;
}
```

Obviously you can include some 'logic' in the `_my_custom_function()` to return your calculated list.

---

Here are a few super-useful link's I wish I would have know about before.

- The [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) has two functions that make hook_form_alter simple as pie... check out [dpm()](http://api.lullabot.com/dpm) and [dd()](http://api.lullabot.com/dd).
- The [FormAPI page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7) is priceless for all things hook_form_alter().
- The [Example Modules for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples) makes for an awesome intro to the FormAPI

Answer (score 0):

write a module and provide a hook_form_alter to change the values of the form element. Just google [hook_form_alter](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=drupal%207%20hook_form_alter) for tutorials and code snippets.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/examples has some form examples too

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a list field?

It has support for a callback to provide the allowed values. See [list_field_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--modules--list--list.module/function/list_field_info/7) That is however not exposed in the UI (which makes somewhat sense as you can't implement a function there either).

So you can simply implement a function that returns the allowed values and then update the field configuration (through api calls in your module, directly in the database, or export your field as a feature and then adjust it there).

In fact, if it is a list field, you probably have to do it this way instead of a hook_form_alter() in order to get past the validation, but I'm not 100% sure.